# When/how to delete a locally declared operation queue?

Tags: objective-c

My code will receive a push notification containing the URL of a remote image to download and display and I was planning on placing a call to NSData:dataWithContentOfURL in an operation queue to run separately from the main thread. 
But I'm not clear on the lifetime of the operation and when/how I should delete it. 
For example suppose I have code similar to this:

```
- (void) onReceiptOfPushNotification:(NSURL*) url
{
    NSOperationQueue *q = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [q addOperationWithBlock: ^{
        NSData*  data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {
            do stuff with the data and image
        }
    }
}
```

My question is as q is a local variable of onReceiptOfPushNotification then when and how to delete it once the operation has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Apple Documentation, ***Operations are removed from the queue only when they finish executing. However, in order to finish executing, an operation must first be started. Because a suspended queue does not start any new operations, it does not remove any operations (including cancelled operations) that are currently queued and not executing.***

So after an NSOperation performed the task to completion, it will be automatically removed from the queue.

Please refer the link [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html), that has each & every detail.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Push notification has a delegate that gets called application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: on every notification. You could make your operation object a singleton and reset it in the delegate.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not feasible if I could receive more than one push before others have completed

Comment: The userInfo object is a dictionary that can be used to explicitly remove a notification.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, why do I want to remove the notification? I want to delete the operation